# A SQL function to return text from a string

Tags: sql, function

I need to return the last name and first name from this string, I have tried replace(replace to remove the 'CN=' and '\' which works however how do I not return anything from the first ',OU'?  Also not all entries have a '\' between the last name and first name.

Current Column example:

```
CN=Doe\,John,OU=Users,OU=Disabled,OU=Something,DC=gas,DC=LOCAL
```

Desired output:

```
Doe, John
```

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Don't store data like that, have separate columns for the different values.

Comment: NB: the backslash is actually there as an escaping character; to show that the comma is part of the name rather than the LDAP path.  As such names formatted `Surname, GivenName` will include a slash before the comma, whilst names formatted `GivenName Surname` will not.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, you can try this set of functions:

```
SELECT REPLACE (
           REPLACE (
               SUBSTR ('CN=Doe\,John,OU=Users,OU=Disabled,OU=Something,DC=gas,DC=LOCAL',
                       4,
                       INSTR ('CN=Doe\,John,OU=Users,OU=Disabled,OU=Something,DC=gas,DC=LOCAL', ',OU') - 4),
               '\',
               ''),
           ',',
           ', ')
           AS resulting_string
  FROM DUAL --your table
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarih these are Oracle funcions. I'll specify it in my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for this.  Here is one method:

```
select x.*, regexp_substr(str, '[^=]+=', 1, 2),
       replace(substr(regexp_substr(str, '[^=]+=', 1, 2), 1,
                      length(regexp_substr(str, '[^=]+=', 1, 2)) - 4
                     ), '\,', ', '
              )
from (select 'CN=Doe\,John,OU=Users,OU=Disabled,OU=Something,DC=gas,DC=LOCAL' as str
      from dual
     ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simplistic SQL Server Solution

SQL Fiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/28903

```
declare @input nvarchar(256) = 'CN=Doe\,John,OU=Users,OU=Disabled,OU=Something,DC=gas,DC=LOCAL' 

select replace(substring(@input,4,charindex(',OU=',@input)-4),'\,',',')
```

This assumes:

- that the string will always be a valid LDAP distinguished name
- that users will always be nested under an OU

Given these assumptions, we can:

- take a substring between the 4th char (i.e. after `CN=` and before the occurrence of the first `,OU=`.
- then use replace to swap any escaped commas with actual commas (we could replace backslash with blank instead, depending on your requirement).

Those assumptions may not be true; so please confirm whether they're appropriate for your scenario.

---

## SQL Server LDAP Query

NB: Since this data relates to LDAP, you may also be interested to know that you can query LDAP directly from SQL; so assuming this data relates to users in your local AD you can get the values straight from the source.

You can create a linked server to LDAP using the steps outlined here: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/03/30/sql-server-query-active-directory-data-using-adsi-ldap-linked-server/

Then use a query such as this to capture the value(s) you're after:

```
Select sn + ', ' + givenName constructedDisplayName
From OpenQuery
(
    ADSI
    ,'Select givenName, sn
    From  ''LDAP://DC=gas,DC=LOCAL'
    Where distinguishedName = ''CN=Doe\,John,OU=Users,OU=Disabled,OU=Something,DC=gas,DC=LOCAL'''
)
```